# Shopify storefront API GraphQL: How to get specific product data?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

Note: I'm new to GraphQL.

Challenge: I use the Shopify Storefront API to create a selectbox of all our products. When a user selects a product in this selectbox, its metafields should be displayed on the page.

I managed to create that selectbox. But how would i display the product-specific data when a choice was made in the selectbox? See current code:

```
function apiCall(productQuery) { 
    return fetch('https://store//api/2022-04/graphql.json', 
        { 
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/graphql', 
                'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': "xxx" 
            }, 
            "body": productQuery 
        }
    )
    .then(
        response => response.json()
    ); 
}

function getProducts() { 
    const productQuery = `{ products(first: 250) { edges { node { id handle title } } } }`; 
    return apiCall(productQuery); 
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    const product_selector_container = $('.product_selector_container'); 
    getProducts().then(response => { 
        product_selector_container.prepend("<select name='product_compatibility_selector' id='product_compatibility_selector'></select>"); 
        const productSelect = $('#product_compatibility_selector');
        const productSelectResult = $("#product_compatibility_result");
        response.data.products.edges.forEach(product => { 
            const optionValues = `<option value="${product.node.handle}">${product.node.title}<option>`; 
            productSelect.append(optionValues); 
        }); 
        
        $("#product_compatibility_selector").on('change', function() {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            var selectedVal = $(this).find('option').val();
            $(".chosen_product_title").text(selected);
            response.data.products.edges.forEach(product => { 
                // HOW DO I REFERENCE THE CURRENT CHOSEN PRODUCT TO OUTPUT VARIOUS NODES?
                const compatibility_result = `${product.node.title}`;
                productSelectResult.append(compatibility_result);
            });
        });
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the handle of the selected produt to retrieve all the metafields of that produt you need to run another query, using the "query" parameter, something like this

```
{
  products(first: 1, query:"handle:your-handle"){
    edges{
      node{
        metafields(first:10){
          edges{
            node{
              value
              key
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  product(handle:"your_handle"){
    title
    metafield(key:"your_key", namespace:"your_space"){
      value
    }

  }
}
```

If you want to parametrize your handle you may want to introduce variables in your query, like this

```
query($handle:String){
  product(handle:$handle){
    title
    metafield(key:"x",namespace:"y"){
      id
      value
    }

  }
}
```

and with the variable object being like

```
{"handle":"your-handle"}
```

In the request instead of just sending the query you send an object like

```
{"query" : your-query, "variables" : variable-object}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I've since come to the solution that i indeed need another query. But now i've stumbled upon another issue, how do i dynamically define "your_handle" in this new query? How do i push the selected product handle to "your_handle"?

Comment: My apologies, but i feel i'm too limited in my knowledge concerning graphQL and making requests. Could i contact you personally?

Comment: Hey @MathijsDelva regarding your question how do you push the selected product handle to "your_handle" is actually how are you doing it, for example do you send data from your shopify store to your app, or are you using webhook

Comment: I am using the storefront API to get data from my Shopify store indeed